# Unity 2D: PlayerPrefs Implementation for Highscore

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I need some assistance implementing a HighScore that saves. Currently, I have a score, which starts from 500,000 and gets down 150 points per seconds. This works, although when I die it still goes on, which I need to fix. I have a second kmHighscore Text, and I want it to show the highscore. Right now it shows the exact score on which I died(for example 450,875), but when I restart the game I can't seem to make it be saved. I tried with PlayerPrefs, but I am not sure how to apply it in my code. I want it to represent the lowest, in this case as it starts from 500,000, score ever achieved. Just to note: Both kmScore and kmHighscore are just numbers, I don't have text before the score or the highscore in the Unity window. Any help will be appreciated!

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class GameOver : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject gameOverScreen;
    public Text kmScore;
    public Text kmHighscore;
    float savedScore;
    bool gameOver;
    private float score = 500000;

    void Start () {
        FindObjectOfType<PlayerController>().OnPlayerDeath += OnGameOver;          
    }

    public void Update () {

        kmScore.text = GetScore().ToString("F0");

        if (gameOver)
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Space))
            {
                SceneManager.LoadScene(1);
            }
        }
    }


    float GetScore()
    {
        return score - (float)Time.timeSinceLevelLoad * 150;
    }


    void OnGameOver()
    {

        gameOverScreen.SetActive (true);
        kmHighscore.text = GetScore().ToString("F0");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change your script to this:

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class GameOver : MonoBehaviour {
    const string PLAYERPREFS_HIGHSCORE = "High Score";
    const int STARTING_SCORE = 500000, POINTS_PER_SECOND = 150;
    public GameObject gameOverScreen;
    public Text kmScore, kmHighscore;
    private int allTimeHighScore, actualScore;
    private bool gameOver;

    private void Start() {
        allTimeHighScore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt(PLAYERPREFS_HIGHSCORE, STARTING_SCORE);
        gameOver = false;
        FindObjectOfType<PlayerController>().OnPlayerDeath += OnGameOver;
        kmHighscore.text = allTimeHighScore.ToString("F0");
    }

    private void Update() {
        if (gameOver) {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) {
                SceneManager.LoadScene(1);
            }
        }
        else {
            kmScore.text = GetScore().ToString("F0");
        }
    }

    private int GetScore() {
        return actualScore = STARTING_SCORE - (int)Time.timeSinceLevelLoad * POINTS_PER_SECOND;
    }

    private void OnGameOver() {
        gameOverScreen.SetActive(true);
        if (allTimeHighScore > GetScore()) {
            kmHighscore.text = (allTimeHighScore = actualScore).ToString("F0");
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt(PLAYERPREFS_HIGHSCORE, allTimeHighScore);
        }
        gameOver = true;
    }
}
```

Couple notes about the code:

- Never use so called "magic numbers" inside your scripts, take advantage of the `const` variables if those variables are immutable.
- I added the use of `gameOver` since you declared it as `private` and it wasn't used anywhere in the class. This will stop the score counting when it's set to `true`.
- Changed the score type to `int`, which is a better fit.

Comment: Thank you for your time! It didn't give me any errors, however, the Highscore stays at 0 after a Restart. So, if I died at 497,000 it will display it as the Highscore, since this was my first playthrough, but after pressing the Restart button, which re-loads the scene the Highscore just stays at: 0. Any ideas?

Comment: This shouldn't happen. Are you absolutely sure you're not using `PlayerPrefs.SetInt` anywhere in your other scripts? Try to run once the game in the editor, then open regedit and check inside HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Unity\UnityEditor\\[CompanyName]\\[ProductName] if the `High Score` value is saved correctly. CompanyName and ProductName are found in the Player settings of Unity

Comment: I deleted them and started a new game. The correct HighScore is indeed saved. However, it appears as: 0 after the first time I die. In the text window in my unity editor the kmHighScore element is with a Text: 0. Just the number. Maybe that's not how it should be?

Comment: You're right, I forgot to update the `kmHighscore.text` in `Start()`, I'll edit the answer to amend the mistake.

Comment: Worked perfectly now. Thank you! I really appreciate that you provided the code. I never worked with PlayerPrefs and I have to admit, the first tries were a disaster.